# Printf statement not outputting

Tags: c, process, fork

Im still relatively new to C, I am currently trying to write a concurrent process program however whenever I get to the child process it only prints out the one section of Printf statements as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int concurrent(int num, int numOfProcs, int *nump)
{
  pid_t pid;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0)
  {
    perror("There was an error during fork call: ");
    exit(1);
  }

  //child Processes
  if (pid == 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfProcs; i++)
    {
      printf("\nBEFORE Increment, ");
      printf(" \nChild number: %d",i);
      printf(" \nChild process ID: %d",(int) getpid());
      printf(" \nCurrent value of num: %d", num);
      printf(" \nCurrent value of nump: %d", *nump);
      printf(" \nCurrent value of x: %d", x);


      x += 5;
      num ++;
      *nump++;

      printf("\nAFTER Increment, ");
      printf(" \nChild number: %d",i);
      printf(" \nChild process ID: %d",(int) getpid());
      printf(" \nCurrent value of num: %d", num);
      printf(" \nCurrent value of nump: %d", *nump);
      printf(" \nCurrent value of x: %d", x);

    }
    exit(0);
  }
  //parent process
  else
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfProcs; i++)
    {
      wait(NULL);
      printf("\nChild Process ended, Child PID: %d",(int) getpid());
    }

  }
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *a = argv[1];
  int numOfProcs = atoi(a);
  x = 10;
  int num = 50;
  int *nump = malloc(100);
  *nump = 100;
  
  printf("\nCurrent Values");
  printf("\nNumber of processes: %d",numOfProcs);
  printf("\nCurrent value of num: %d", num);
  printf("\nCurrent value of nump: %d", *nump);
  printf("\nCurrent value of x: %d", x);

  concurrent(num,numOfProcs,&nump);

  exit(0);
}
```

here is the output as of right now:

```
Current Values
Number of processes: 2
Current value of num: 50
Current value of nump: 100
Current value of x: 10
BEFORE Increment,  
Child number: 0 
Child process ID: 35148 
Current value of x: 10
Child Process ended, Child PID: 35147
Child Process ended, Child PID: 35147
```

Im just a bit confused on why its not outputting "AFTER Increment" and the rest of the print statements, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It probably crashed because `nump` was invalid.

Comment: `*nump++` - what do you expect this to do?

Comment: Aside: it's more usual to output the `\n` after every line's content, not before. Especially when you are relying on the output for debugging cues, the `\n` will flush the buffered output.

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a [mre]. There are lines in your output that are not in the code you've shown.

Comment: Are you running a stale executable? (Did you get build errors?)

Comment: `*nump++;` should probably be `(*nump)++;` or `++*nump;` - You could also check that a child actually finished by capturing the return value from `wait`, like `pid_t child = wait(NULL); if(child != -1) { printf("child %d died\n", child); } else { /* all children dead */ }`

Comment: @EugeneSh. nump is an integer pointer assigned a value of 100, I was trying to increment that value to 101.

Comment: @CH So it is not what it does. It is dereferencing the pointer and then incrementing it (the pointer, not the value). So the next time it will try to dereference an invalid pointer.

Comment: Check [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Postfix `++` has higher precedence than `*` so what you are doing is actually `*(nump++);`, you increase the _pointer_ (not the value it points at) and then dereference that pointer.

Comment: So I assigned *nump in main, so how would I pass the value to the concurrent function? The current function call I have is                                                            
      `concurrent(num,numOfProcs,*nump);`

Comment: If you have another question (and looks like you do) - ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

There's some issues that you can find building the binary with `-Wall`:

- `x` is uninitialized
- `*nump++`: `the value is not used` (because you increase the *pointer* `nump`, not the value it's pointing at - and *then* dereference the pointer, see [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence))

Here's the code with the fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int concurrent(int num, int numOfProcs, int *nump)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int x = 0;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0)
  {
    perror("There was an error during fork call: ");
    exit(1);
  }

  //child Processes
  if (pid == 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfProcs; i++)
    {
      printf("\nBEFORE Increment, ");
      printf(" \nChild number: %d",i);
      printf(" \nChild process ID: %d",(int) getpid());
      printf(" \nCurrent value of num: %d", num);
      printf(" \nCurrent value of nump: %d", *nump);
      printf(" \nCurrent value of x: %d", x);

      x += 5;
      num ++;
      (*nump)++;

      printf("\nAFTER Increment, ");
      printf(" \nChild number: %d",i);
      printf(" \nChild process ID: %d",(int) getpid());
      printf(" \nCurrent value of num: %d", num);
      printf(" \nCurrent value of nump: %d", *nump);
      printf(" \nCurrent value of x: %d", x);

    }
    exit(0);
  }
  //parent process
  else
  {
    pid_t child;
    while((child = wait(NULL)) != -1) {
      printf("\nChild Process ended, Child PID: %d", (int)child);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int main()
{
   int nump = 100;
   return concurrent(50, 2, &nump);
}
```

Comment: I think another issue is that OP only spawns _one_ process (outside the `numOfProcs` loop).  A possible fix could be [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/c55cxnj8h)